# How to add local maven projects as modules to an sbt/Play project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a Maven project ("example-square"), which provides classes to calculate the square and cube of an integer.
I also have a sbt/Play framework project ("sbt_hello"), which uses the square and cube classes from "example-square". I want to extend my "example-square" project with a number of new classes (e.g. adding a square-root class) as I go.

To get everything work together, I've included my Maven project as a library dependency in my `build.sbt`, but I've also added it as a module in IntelliJ (using `File > Project Structure > Modules > sbt_hello > Dependencies > Add Module Dependency...`).
Running my test classes, which use the square and cube classes, is completely successful. All changes in the code are immediately reflected into the tests.

However, when I'm refreshing my sbt project or try to run the Play project, I get the error message that there is an unresolved dependency path.

I guess adding it as a module in IntelliJ is what allows the tests to run successfully, and adding it to the library dependencies is what makes sbt look for the jars (which I do want?), it's just looking at the wrong places. According to the error log, sbt is only looking at following folders:

```
[warn]  module not found: example#example-square;1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\just_me\.ivy2\local\example\example-square\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/example/example-square/1.0-SNAPSHOT/example-square-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\just_me\.sbt\preloaded\example\example-square\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/just_me/.sbt/preloaded/example/example-square/1.0-SNAPSHOT/example-square-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Of course the package is not there, since it's a Maven project and I didn't run mvn install (even if I did, the jars would have been installed into `.m2`).

I've tried adding my module via `File > Project Structure > Modules > sbt_hello > Sources > Add Content Root` before, as it is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html), but IntelliJ keeps removing this module, when I update my sbt project.

**Q: How do I properly point to the actual Maven project from my sbt/Play project when using IntelliJ?**

Btw, I'm totally new to sbt/Play and Scala in general (I've worked with Java before though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add to your build.sbt:
   `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`
2. Install by `mvn install` project to local maven repository ($USER/.m2).
3. Add dependency to your build.sbt file.

Second alternative is to use artifactory to publish local projects.

Comment: Thank you! This worked - is there another way without using "mvn install"?

Comment: It is the simplest solution. Sbt reads only from repositories (ivy or maven).

Comment: This worked. but i was looking for an option which skips this manual step for mvn install. Because when ever i change the code i need to make sure i update the jar.